# need help to find a php structure solution

Tags: php

I am just a student at php, I am trying to find out a list of members from a table where I dont know how much rows are in that table, but I need every 6 rows on `Order By entrytime DESC` basis.
My table structure is as below:

```
int `ID`
int `entrytime` // this time updates when rows insert
```

now I need to find out all ids on basis of `entrytime DESC` and insert those ids in a separate new table say "new_tbl" as a group of 6 ids

```
ind `ID`
varchar `group_name`
```

I am trying to do like this :

```
$qry=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM main_table entrytime ASC");
while($res=mysql_fetch_row($qry)){
    $id=$res['0'];
    $q=mysql_query();

######### But not getting any Idea how to find every 6 Ids and insert in new_tbl #######

}
```

Comment: tip: though mysql_* This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future, better to use PDO.
and for this situation use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you use `mysql_fetch_row` this gives you the count of rows and not the data.

```
while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)) {
```

To get the Data you have to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` for example.

To find every 6 Ids you can make a counter and increment the value by 1. If the modulo of 6 and the value is 0 you have the sixth value and you can reset the counter.

```
$i = 1;

while ... 
   if($i % 6 == 0) {
      // reset your counter
      $i = 1;
   }
   $i++;
}
```

Then you can use the counter to work with it and write that to another table for example.